# MultiBrands - Same Business Unit - Multi SAP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, deliverability

We have multiple brands (10) under a single parent brand, and would like the images and links on those brands to be branded.

The total email volume of all brands are enough for SAP, but not for the individual brands.

The email content is shared (That's why they are in the same BU), but the branding changes (BrandName, Links and Images)

My understanding is that we would set SAP up under the parent brand, and then have private domains for the sub brands.

The problem with that is that the sub brands won't have branded images and links.

Hypothetically, could be pay for 10 SAP's in a single BU to get branding? (and only use 1 IP as the volume would be too low) OR when you get SAP is your IP and domain tied together and needs to be used together (RNDS?)

Any other way for us to do this?

Currently this is setup with a different esp and works perfectly as there is no SAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have exactly 1 SAP per Business Unit.

Assuming you bought 10 SAPs, you'd need 10 BUs to install them.
Private Domains indeed do not brand images and links.

Quoting an SF presentation on the subject:

> Q: Can we put multiple SAPs on 1 account? A: No, a single MID can only support 1 SAP for branding purposes (i.e. the links and images can only point to 1 domain). This is a limitation of the way brand tags work. You can have multiple Private Domains on a single MID. This means the client could send from multiple FROM addresses but the links and images would always point back to the SAP domain chosen.

The P in SAP is for "Package", you cannot disassociate elements from within the product, meaning you cannot get separate branding for emails / links without an SAP.

Quoting an SF presentation on the subject:

> SAP is actually a collection of products including Private Domain with link and image wrapping, Dedicated IP and RMM. While these other products can  purchased individually, the link and image wrapping that truly “brands” the  account only comes with SAP.

In summary: "full branding" (link & image & brand) comes only with a BU & SAP *per brand*.

Edit:

in case someone finds this with regards to cloudpages, there is a nice little gotcha.

If you choose to brand inside the same BU using just private domains (without link branding etc) - You *can* have separate private domains for cloudpages inside the same BU, by purchasing private domains (& SSl certificates), with one interesting limitation:

each pagename can only be assigned once across *all* private domains in one BU.

Meaning once you have "cloud.news.test.com/myPage", that blocks creation of "cloud.news.myOtherDomain.com/myPage" if they are in the same BU on two private subdomains (news.test.com / news.myOtherDomain.com). So you need to have unique pagenames nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. that answered my questions.